# LWC Folder Structure

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

Id there a way to organize my components inside sub folders and not having them saved directly under LWC?

Just a simple example, if I have 10 components related to Contacts and another 10 related to Account, I'd like to have a folder structure such as ".../lwc/AccountComponenets/" and ".../lwc/ContactComponenets/".

This is really annoying to have countless unrelated components under the same root.

Any time I tried to do so I got endless compilation errors. Right now it's getting impossible to manage the project :-\

(using VSCode, Salesforce DX)

Thanks!
- Shai

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. All components must be saved in a lwc folder. However, you can have multiple lwc folders in DX:

```
/force-app/accounts/main/default/lwc/myAccountComponent1
...
/force-app/contacts/main/default/lwc/myContactComponent1
...
```

Each path is configured in sfdx-project.json:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        { "path": "force-app/accounts", "default": true },
        { "path": "force-app/contacts", "default": false }
    ]
    // ... //
}
```

This design allows you to create unlocked packages, with possible dependencies, using LWC components and/or other types of metadata.

Package directories are described in the [DX Project Configuration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm) documentation and you can read more about [Unlocked Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_workflow.htm) as well.

Comment: Ah, hmm, this is a bit weird. Can you please share the link from where you got this?
Thanks!

Comment: @Shai I edited in two links that should hopefully help. The idea is that each source-format directory contains self-contained "apps", which can have dependencies on other apps, and helps organize functionality in the way you're looking for. I admit, it's definitely different than what we thought folder-based organization was going to look like, but it certainly works once you're used to it.

Comment: Thank you once again. Need to see how to manage this in GIT as well

Comment: @Shai It's pretty much what you'd expect. Pretty easy to manage, I've created 7 or so unlocked packages already, it plays pretty good with git.

Comment: Was trying to create sub folder structure inside VS code to place LWCs nicely. That works. Was able to deploy. However if you RETRIEVE this in a new project, the sub folder structure will not be maintained as on SF side there is no sub folder concept. It is all under one lwc folder. So in reality no much use unless you are one person deve and your project structure remains same for a long time ( dev + maintenance ) or you copy the entire local dev structure to new machine.