# LWC Folder Structure: Import AND render components from other lwc directories

Tags: lightning-web-components, architecture, folder

Trying to reorganize folder structure as all components are currently under 1 lwc folder. Came across this post [LWC Folder Structure](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289749/lwc-folder-structure)

It answers the first problem of overcrowding unrelated components in 1 folder. But is it possible to import lwc components from other lwc folders? I didn't see anything in the OP docs about this.

To be clear, I'm talking about entire components with html, css, js and xml - not just utility functions.

Thank you

Comment: This is should answer your question [Importing ES6 module in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274261/importing-es6-module-in-lwc-project-sfdx)

Comment: @Klecool  I'm not looking to import utility functions, I'm looking to important entire components (each with their own child components) much like is standard in React.js or other modern JS frameworks.

Comment: @sfdcfox no sir, see above comment

Comment: Okay, so what are you trying to do with this import?

Comment: @sfdcfox Render the component.

Comment: @T.Young If I understand your request, what you're asking simply isn't possible in LWC. The way you'd render a component is to put it in to a template. You can use multiple templates and choose one with the render() callback, but that's about it.